# how to use @step annotation for lambda expression in allure-junit-adaptor

Tags: allure

use:
ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-junit-adaptor 1.5.0

want use @Step annotation for field with lambda expression:

```
@Step("Assert screens")
 protected AssertScreenshotsInterface compareScreenshots = () -> assertThat(compareImages(getEtalonScreenshotPath(), getCurrentScreenshotPath(),
    getDifferentScreenshotPath())).isTrue();
```

ide show hint: "@Step not applicable to field".  I use it function in every test, how to support lambda in allure report?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at moment, as [Steps's](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/master/allure-java-commons/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/Step.java#L14) target is `METHOD`.
But you can create a feature request in [allure-java](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java) project, if it's really important for you.